# Where can I get a legitimate copy of ocsetup.exe?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I am running into an issue with Windows Server 2012. After doing some searching, this is the best answer I could find to solve it:

> ... ocsetup.exe is not included in Server 2012 R2 like it was in previous versions. So to resolve the issue you had to copy this ocsetup.exe file from Server2008 R2 DVD into the *system32* directory on your Server2012R2 ...

Now the problem is that I don't have a Server2008 R2 DVD from witch to copy this file. Can anyone tell me where else I can get a legitimate copy of Server2008 R2's ocsetup.exe?

Comment: I don't understand why this question got down-voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download Windows Server 2008 R2 Evaluation ISO from Microsoft: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11093 and extract the files you need.

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware that the ISO's could be downloaded like this.